# Error: "Please verify that you have been granted access to DocuSign"

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

We are using esignautre app luncher (Apex toolkit) in Salesforce, the user has "DocuSign User" Permission.

[image]

The user is getting this below error when is retrieving the template using the app launcher. When below page loads, it calls dfsle.TemplateService.getTemplates() method in apex. This method came with esignature app launcher managed app.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/templateservice.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Will you please explain a little bit more about your use case and how you have it implemented so far?

If you're expecting a standard Salesforce user to trigger your apex to send a DocuSign envelope transaction, then your standard user needs the "DocuSign Sender" permission set assignment assigned to them, not "DocuSign User". But would need to know more about your use case and requirements to provide further assistance.

Here's more documentation that might help you:

Understanding DocuSign Permission Sets in Salesforce: https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=srl1586134368658&topicId=xxm1623778416524.html&_LANG=enus

Enable a System Sender To Let Non-DocuSign Users Send and Sign Envelopes With the Apex Toolkit﻿: https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=srl1586134368658&topicId=jxz1611642321527.html&_LANG=enus

Comment: i gave user all the docusign permissions and still have the issue. we created an lwc component that gets all templates from docusign. When the user select the template and click on send, the envlope gets sent to the end user. We build this using apex toolkit from the app luncher managed package. However, this error is happening when the user retrive all template in docusign using the apex method.